# Non-parametrized partial match query

Tags: sql, ms-access, match, partial

I'm an access beginner.

I'm trying to write a query that finds all partial matches between a field in one table and a field in another.

I'll give a simplified example of what I'm looking for as a final result and maybe you can help me write the SQL for it.

Table 1: Strings

```
pre
ing
up
```

Table 2: Words

```
present
door
cup
making
kingdom
```

Desired Result Table:

```
pre     present
up      cup
ing     kingdom
ing     making
```

Here's what I have - it can give me a prompt where I type in what I'm looking for. (e.g. if I type in 'up', then I get cup from the word list). What I want is a way to automate the whole process for all of the strings in the first list.

```
SELECT *
FROM word
WHERE (((word) LIKE "*" & string & "*"));
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access in front of me, but I think you can do something similar to this (this is for SQL Server):

```
select stringname, wordname
from strings
  join words on wordname like '%' + stringname + '%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2140/1)

If I had to guess at the Access syntax, replace % with * and possibly change the + to &, but hopefully this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: . . I think the correct syntax in Access uses `&` rather than `+`.  And the `like` operator uses `*` for the wildcard instead of `%`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- thx, it's been a while since I've used Access :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But, I tried both ways but I seem to keep getting syntax error messages.Suppose I have [strings].[fielda] and [words].[fieldb]. I wrote:                                              SELECT [strings].[fielda],[words].[fieldb] FROM strings JOIN words ON [words].[fieldb] LIKE '*' & [strings].[fielda] & '*';

Comment: @Cabral -- what errors are you getting?  Your query looks right (except you left off the * in your like).

Comment: Try `SELECT [strings].[fielda], [words].[fieldb] FROM strings, words WHERE [words].[fieldb] LIKE "*" & [strings].[fielda] & "*"`

Comment: Double quotes seemed to work. (That was a typo with me leaving out the *) Thanks so much everyone!